# How can I tell PHP to dump exceptions as raw text instead of HTML?

Tags: php, error-handling

When I'm developing my REST API in PHP I'm working with `application/json` output, so when I get errors while testing in the browser they look like this:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'PDO caught an error:
array(3) {
  [0]=&gt;
  string(5) &quot;42000&quot;
  [1]=&gt;
  int(1065)
  [2]=&gt;
  string(15) &quot;Query was empty&quot;
}
```

And it gets worse when I get large stack traces and stuff. So is there a flag I can set telling PHP that I want my errors unescaped and in raw text?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a `php.ini` setting called [`html_errors`](http://php.net/manual/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.html-errors).

Answer (score 7):

In your *php.ini* you can set three different settings to change how HTML errors are displayed.

- [`html_errors`](http://php.net/html-errors)
- [`error_prepend_string`](http://php.net/error-prepend-string) String to output before an error message
- [`error_append_string`](http://php.net/error-append-string) String to output after an error message

I use the following in my development environment:

```
html_errors = On
error_prepend_string = "<pre>"
error_append_string = "</pre>"
```

Comment: Also don't forget to set enough [`log_errors_max_len`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors-max-len).

Answer (score 0):

There may be some configuration option that I can't find to do this - I suspect there is, since the HTML is not present on the command line.

A dirty work around is to pass the strings through `html_entity_decode(strip_tags($str))`.

**EDIT** As Andy Pieters has pointed out (he is obviously better at reading docs than I am) there is a configuration option called [`html_errors`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.html-errors) to control this. I will leave this answer here in case for some reason you cannot modify this, but you should probably accept his answer.