# How to make PHP errors in text instead of HTML

Tags: php, error-handling, login-script

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I tell PHP to dump exceptions as raw text instead of HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941243/how-can-i-tell-php-to-dump-exceptions-as-raw-text-instead-of-html)

I am trying to make a login script using C# and php and I plan on selling it as a 1 click install so I need it to be error proof. I am purposely trying to make mistakes in the setup, but whenever my php script has a mistake it has an HTML block output with the error when I just want a string output(refer to image).

Heres the code I am using

```
// We will now set up our MySQL database login. The values should be self-explanatory. 
$sqlhost = "localhost";
$sqlusername = "unity";
$sqlpassword = "mypass123";

//we will now connect to our database
$sqlcon = mysql_connect($sqlhost, $sqlusername, $sqlpassword) or die("Could not connect to database: " . mysql_error());
```

When I have all the information it works fine and the rest of the code runs without an error. But if my password is wrong or the user doesn't have access then I get this error

[image: Error I am trying to avoid]

I am retrieved the information from this page and it needs to be sent as plan text to be displayed properly. What I mean by this is that any HTML tags like `<div>, <br>, <a>,` etc and just generally makes the text output look bad. I want this to just display the text at the bottom the page because that logs the error itself. I dont need it to log twice and I dont need it to be formatted fancy. I need it in plain readable text so that if a user has an error they can send me the short text and I will be able to walk them through the fix.

Comment: Did you read the manual regarding error reporting and display?  The answer to your question can be found there.  Also, don't use mysql_* for database access, they're old, barely maintained and deprecated in all but name.

Comment: No I have not, I'm not big on PHP, I do mostly C# and just needed a simple PHP backend file. I did some google searches for awhile and didn't turn anything up besides completely turning error reporting off which I didn't feel was the best idea. And what should I use in replace of mysql_*? is there something newer/better for connecting to a database?

Comment: @ViperCode What you're likely looking for is the display_errors setting.  If display_errors is set to off, then errors will still be logged. There's also html_errors though (though your screenshot looks like error HTML generated by xdebug, so you might need to find the right xdebug setting).

Comment: I just tried: error_reporting(0);
in the file to turn off error reporting(only in this file I'm assuming) and thats fine because if there are any other errors that an end user would run into then they screwed up my code and thats an easy fix. Now I'm more concerned about the outdated mysql_* functions

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Whether PHP displays plain text or html errors depends on your [php.ini configuration](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.html-errors):

> **`html_errors`** `boolean`
>
> Turn off HTML tags in error messages. The new format for HTML errors produces clickable messages that direct the user to a page describing the error or function in causing the error. These references are affected by docref_root and docref_ext.

The setting is [settable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) as `PHP_INI_ALL`, which means anywhere, including your script. So to disable html errors do

```
ini_set('html_errors', false);
```

at the beginning of your script.

Comment: This also works great when xdebug is on. Previously I was calling `xdebug_disable()`, but that's no longer necessary with this variable.

Comment: Just a note - it also seems to work if you invoke the ini_set call immediately before the expected error is to occur. This is handy if (for example) your output format is dependent on runtime conditions (i.e. HTML vs. plaintext only decided at runtime)